# Why $\gcd(a,a+N) =1$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, prime-factorization

By experiment, I notice that $$\gcd(a,a+N) =1$$
Where $N$ is a big composite integer number that is hard to factor and does not have a common divisor with $a$. And $a$ is a positive big integer that might be bigger than $N$.

Is it really the case, and if so then why it's happening?

Comment: Because GCD$(a,N)=1$...  essentially, $a$ is coprime with any integer that shares no prime factors with it...

Comment: The underlying reason is that $\mathrm{gcd}(a,a+N) = \mathrm{gcd}(a,N)$ for any $a,N$.  In your case, you have $\mathrm{gcd}(a,N) = 1$, leading to your observation.

Comment: @mark will it be also true to say that $gcd(a\mod{N},a\mod{N}+N)=1$ if $gcd(a,N)=1$

Comment: " and does not have a common divisor with $a $." That's why.  If $p $ is a facter of $a $ and $p $ is a factor of $a+N $ then $p $ is a factor of $a+N-a=N $.  But you specified $a $ and $N $ have no factors in common.  So $a$ and $a+N $ have no factors in common

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in general $$gcd(a,b)=gcd(a,a-b)$$ then $$gcd(a,a+N)=gcd(a,a+N-a)=gcd(a,N)=1$$

Answer (score 0):

When the $\gcd$ of two numbers is $1$, all that means is that they have no common divisors (other than $\pm 1$). If $N$ has no common divisor with $a$, then neither does $a+N$.